# How to disable assets compilation for certain environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, capistrano3

For my `Rails 3.2`/`Capistrano 3` application I configured 2 deploy environments: `staging` and `production`.

I don't want to spend time on assets compilation when deploy to `staging`, since it should be the same as local `development`.

In my `Capfile` I have

```
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
```

which is needed for `production`, but with this line `Capistrano` also compiles assets for all other environments.

How can I configure it to compile assets(or skip compilation) for specific environments?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to config/environments/staging.rb file

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

Comment: thanks, this was what I tried first, even with it, capistrano tries to run precompile task which ends with exception